# ImageMagick.NET Exception

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am getting a `FileNotFoundException` when trying to use ImageMagick.NET, taken from the "bin" folder in the source at.. http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/releases/view/30302

The exact exception I get is...

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'ImageMagickNET.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module
>   could not be found."

The ImageMagickNET.dll is in my output folder, so what other dependencies does it need?

Comment: There is a conversation about this issue on their project forum: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/discussions/66874

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" is the typical problem with a mixed-mode assembly.  Troubleshoot with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see it searching for the DLL just before your program fails.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm sure you know this already, but for troubleshooting .Net DLL issues such as this I always go right to ildasm.exe to examine the dependencies of the DLL in question after looking at the fusion logs to see if they provide any clues. I personally find this much easier that trying to filter down procmon output.

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a Reference to the 'ImageMagickNet.dll' found in the 'bin\ReleaseQ8' or 'bin\RealeaseQ16' folders, choose one of them.

After that you have to download the ImageMagick 6.5.3-10 version DLLs for Q8/Q16 because the ImageMagickNet was built to this version.
(I found all versions at this link: http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/
For example, for Q16 download: ImageMagick-6.5.3-10-Q16-windows-dll.exe)

Then install it and copy all DLL files from 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q16' to your bin folder.
Now you should be able to run it properly.

Comment: Marked as correct answer. Even though I found a different solution a while back.

Comment: @Twitchy If you found another solution, could you share it with us? You can post answer to your own question.

Comment: You actually don't even need to copy the DLLs to your bin as long as you run the installer.

Comment: I get the same error in Unit Test, I copy dlls using  [DeploymentItem(@"F:\ToolsImg\ImageMagick-6.8.1-Q16")]