# Unable to Use Image Magick (Magick Net)

Tags: c#, .net, image, imagemagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ImageMagick.NET Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555454/imagemagick-net-exception)

Im trying to use ImageMagick to sharpen an Image

```
        ImageMagickNET.Image g = new ImageMagickNET.Image(@"I:\My Photos\a.jpg");
        g.Sharpen(1, 2);

        pictureBox1.Image = g.ToBitmap();
```

Even after referencing the assemblies and placing the assembly in the executable folder.A FileNotFound Exception saying ImageMagickNET.dll cannot be found is thrown.What could be the problem.Is this the correct way to use ImageMagick.Can someone please give any example.